# FDR controlling demonstration in R

Tags: r, multiple-comparisons, false-discovery-rate

I'm trying to demonstrate BH method for controlling false discovery rate in R.

The problem is that I get quite unexpected results (so I assume that something is going wrong with this)

```
set.seed(4)
x = matrix(rnorm(100*5),nrow=100)
set.seed(5)
y = matrix(rnorm(100*5),nrow=100)
set.seed(6)
y[81:100,]= rnorm(100, mean=3)
```

The p-values are produces from above distributions. (So the first 80 p-values are coming from true null distribution and the rest 20 follow the alternative distribution.)

```
p = sapply(1:100, function(i) t.test(x[i,],y[i,])$p.val)
sort.p<-sort(p)
```

Then the BH procedure is defined as follows  (p_i<= q*i/n) (n=100, q=0.1) :

```
eq<-function(){(q*(1:n))/n}

rej.pvals <- sort.p[sort.p<=eq()]     #Find all the p-values which are smaller than q*i/n
```

After that I found the largest i which satisfy that equation. And in this example that is p_24. So I have 24 rejected p-values. The problem is that among these 24 rejected p-values, I have 4 true null hypothesis (=false discoveries). So the FDR is 4/24=0.167 which is greater than the selected q=0.1..

```
> sum(match(rej.p,p)<=80)
[1] 4
```

Can some help me to undestand what I'm missing there? 
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you seem to be computing is not the FDR, but the FDP - the false discovery proportion.

The FDR $Q_e$ is the expected value of the FDP, i.e., the *proportion* of false rejections $v$ to all rejections $r$,

$$Q_e=E\left(\frac{V}{R}\right)=E\left(\frac{V}{V+S}\right)=:E\left(Q\right).$$

The Benjamini-Hochberg procedure promises to control the FDR, i.e., that the expected proportion of false rejections is less than $q$, but, unfortunately, not necessarily the proportion itself.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer. But I'm still little uncertain, since in this case I know the count of true null hypothesis, so in that case would it be that FDR=FDP?

Comment: No. In this case, in which you generate the data, you are in the position to verify that the r.v. (the FDP) takes a larger value than its expectation, the FDR: $0.167>0.1$. In practice you would not know that as, as you point out, you would not know how many nulls are false. That is basically the same situation in a standard hypothesis test, in which you do not know if a rejection is the right decision or a type-I error.